# Laravel 5.5 testing ModelNotFoundException exception for delete api routes

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, phpunit

I'm having odd behaviour in a laravel 5.5 project.  I have some feature tests set up and working, and need to test that a specific route will return a 404 if the id passed in doesn't exist.  I have explicit model binding set up in the `RouteServiceProvider` for my `Note` model

```
Route::bind('note', function($value){
    return Note::where('id', $value)->first() ?? abort(404);
});
```

This works for my get route test.  This test below passes as expected. (`$this->headers` is just some bits I set in a setUp method that is needed for a lot of the tests)

```
/** @test */
public function error_received_if_note_does_not_exist()
{
    $this->withExceptionHandling();

    $response = $this->json('GET', '/api/v1/note/1', [], $this->headers);
    $response->assertStatus(404);
}
```

but this one for the delete route fails ...

```
/**
 * @test
 * @expectedException \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException
 */
public function error_received_if_note_not_found()
{
    $this->withExceptionHandling();

    $response = $this->json('DELETE', '/api/v1/note/1', [], $this->headers);
    $response->assertStatus(404);
}
```

with message 
`Failed asserting that exception of type "\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException" is thrown.`

I get that technically the exception is correct, but I want to assert that I get a 404 error code.

Here is the routes/api.php file

```
Route::apiResource('note', 'NoteController')->only([
    'show',
    'destroy'
]);
```

I'm pulling my hair out.  Any ideas welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think Ive figured this out encase anyone else has this problem.

In the delete test, I removed the `$this->withExceptionHandling();` line.  Which then allows the test to pass.

If I do the same in the get test it fails.  So the get test needs it, but the delete test doesn't.

Randomly.